# Can't access other drives

Tags: 12.10, mount, hard-drive, acl

My 500 gb hard drive with windows 7 has recently crashed with all my personal files on it.  I have called HP and have a new hdd in the mail but I am unable to remove old files from the old hdd.  I am a pretty good with computers and have put ubuntu on a flash drive in the hopes of accessing my files and moving them to an external hdd.  But I have run into an error "adding read ACL for uid 1000 to' /media/USERNAME' failed: Operation not supported."  I have read several pages on the same problem but I am new to ubuntu and can not figure out what to do. Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear but I am assuming that  this happens either when you plug in the external drive, or possibly when trying to mount the 500Gb internal drive.

It should still be possible to mount these drives from the command line.

If you open up a terminal you can use the following command to identify the disks:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

this will list the hard drives installed.

The internal hard drive should be /dev/sda. Divided into partitions such as /dev/sda1 etc. The external disk will probably show up as /dev/sdb1. You can often confirm which is which by the disk size given.

Next you will need to create mount points for them.

```
 sudo mkdir /media/disk1
 sudo mkdir /media/disk2
```

now you can mount them manually

```
sudo mount -t ntfs /dev/sda1 /mnt/disk1
sudo mount -t ntfs /dev/sdb1 /mnt/disk2
```

-t refers to the file system type. I am assuming these are ntfs if you have come from Windows. You will need to make sure you have the right partitions.

Once this is done you can copy files through the GUI assuming there are no other issues with the disk(s).